# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x68) in second read method

Tags: c++, xcode, scanf, fopen

I am relatively new to using Xcode for c++.

My problem is the following:

I am trying to read two txt file using fopen for which I made two different methods (in the example code I only have one method for keeping it short)  Both methods for reading the files work perfect seperatly, i.e. when I test them alone in the main, they read the data perfectly from the file. However if I call both methods together in the main, the exception "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x68)" is thrown when reading the second txt file. So it seems to be impossible to open and read more than 1 file. My code looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

float fl[10];

void readfile(std::string s){
    strcat(filename, s.c_str());
    input = fopen(filename, "r");
    for (int i == 0; i < 10; i++){
       fscanf(input, "%f\t", fl[i]);
    }
    fclose(input);
}
```

Following main works

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::string s1 = "Input1"; 
    readfile(s1);
    return 0;
}
```

In this main the exception is thrown in the method readfile(s2).

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::string s1 = "Input1.txt"; 
    std::string s2 = "Input2.txt";
    readfile(s1);
    readfile(s2);
    return 0;
}
```

The txt files input1 and input2 contain 10 float numbers each separated by tabs.

The exception is thrown at the fscanf line. Does anyone have a clue on what the problem might be?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you choose to you use C mechanisms for this?

Comment: It's not clear from the provided code what the problem is. Notably, there is no hint as to what `fl` or `filename` are. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: I choose C++ because it happens to be something I learned in the past, no other reason than that :) My actual code is langer and the info in the txt files as well. I made a small code example that gives the same exception, to illustrate my problem. 

Like mentioned in the comment, fl is an array of floats: float fl[10]; However I think the code is not the issue and It will rather be something in the settings of Xcode I guess.

Comment: I edited the code. I hope this provides more details and if you need more info to be able to figure out the problem, please ask.

Comment: No, you are using C mechanisms, not C++. Your code is not complete, so we cannot easily reproduce your issue. And you should [Google your error messages](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-exc_bad_access-and-how-to-debug-it--cms-24544)

Comment: Also [check the C++ tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

Comment: I did google the problem and did not find any explanation for my problem.

Comment: if you say that the problem only occurs when call both readfile functions wouldn't it be appropriate to show both then? Judging from the array "filename" if it is global and you have that in both functions without initializing it there is a high risk that is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Should have used 'strcpy' instead of 'strcat'. Thx for the help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You never initialise `i`.

`for (int i == 0; i < 10; i++){`

should be:

`for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){`

`i` will likely contain garbage which causes you to dereference random bits of memory and gives your bad access.